# Img in <div> don't show

Tags: html, css

Image in my `<div=img-header>` doesn't show under the writing, it appear only the writing but not the image, I've tried many ways but ther was unsuceesful.
Someone can help me?

I've tried change class in id, manually resize img, change the css code, change name:

```css
.img-header {
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-image: url('img/header.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header class="img-header">
 <div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
   <div class="col-12 text-center">
    <h1 class="font-weight-light">My Site</h1>
    <p class="lead">Welcome to My site!</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

The image from div should appear under the writing "My site - Welcome to my site".

Comment: make sure you have specified the right path: `background-image: url('img/header.jpg');`

Comment: i've specified the right path, i've tried too with a hosted img but the result is the same

Comment: write z-index:1; in your css code then try.

Comment: You're not using Ad-block or anything like that?

Comment: seems like you might not be getting the path right to your img is all, try `../img/header.jpg` to go up one directory. You do have an img folder in your solution, yes?

Comment: or `~/img/header.jpg` will go to the root directory of your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your .css file is correctly linked.
Use browser developer tools to inspect the div and verify if the image is reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this background-image: url('/img/header.jpg');
instead of background-image: url('img/header.jpg');
Always provide appropriate path.